# JSTL Round off/down number

Tags: java, jsp, tags, jstl, rounding

This might be a dumb question, but let's say I have a variable `seconds` in my JSP page and its value is 779. Now I want to convert it into minutes and seconds by doing the following:

```
    <c:set var="${seconds / 60}" value="min"/>
    <c:set var="${seconds mod 60}" value="sec">
```

This way I get min = 12.983333 and sec = 59.0.

Now I want to merge the two and display the result as 12:59. The problem I am facing is that `min` keeps getting rounded up to 13. I have tried many things, such as:

```
    <fmt:parseNumber var="minutes" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${min}" />

    <fmt:formatNumber type="number" pattern="###" value="${min}" var="minutes" />

    fn:substringBefore(min, '.')

    maxFractionDigits="0"

    // and so on...
```

But all of them just return 13 consistently. I am a bit clueless at this point. But I may have missed something. I hope someone here has an idea, or a hint, about what might be wrong.

**-edit**

The code below made it work in the end. I have no clue what was wrong, since its also working with "/" now. Maybe some minor mistake elsewhere. Nevertheless thanks a lot for your time :)  Kudos!

```
    <c:set var="min" value="${fn:substringBefore((seconds div 60), '.')}"/>  
    <fmt:formatNumber var="sec" pattern="##" value="${seconds mod 60)}"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This (below) should be the only safe way to do it. pattern="##" is not well supported, minIntegerDigits="2" is easier and cleaner.

```
<c:set var="minutes" value="${fn:substringBefore(seconds div 60, '.')}"/> 
<fmt:formatNumber var="seconds" minIntegerDigits="2" value="${ seconds - (minutes*60) }"/>
```

Comment: `fn:substringBefore` is the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use integral division to get the value for `min`, instead of floating point division:

```
<c:set var="min" value="${seconds div 60}" />
```

Now you get min = 12, and you don't have to worry about the rounding issues.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me, `<c:set var="min" value="${29 div 10}" />` gives me 2.9